# alert dialog edit text returns no value

Tags: java, android

I have an alert dialog with a xml layout for it and it has an edit text. When I write some text and press SAVE,
the editText to String returns null. Here is my code -

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

        alertDialogBuilder.setView(R.layout.dialog_layout);

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("SAVE",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                EditText userInput = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
                                dbUtils.insertCSVFileName(userInput.getText().toString());
                                Log.d("hi","vaqlue of edittext" + userInput.getText().toString());  //gives me null

                            }
                        })
```

My edit text is present in `dialog_layout.xml`. Why is this null?

Comment: `alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);` &    `alertDialogBuilder.setView(R.layout.dialog_layout);` ....please us only one of both...

Comment: why `alertDialogBuilder.setView(R.layout.dialog_layout);` ??

Comment: Try to use trim.     userInput.getText().toString().trim();

Comment: @Opiatefuchs super thank you it worked :)

Comment: @Ratilal...how should `trim()` prevent to get `null` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you set the layout twice:

```
alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
alertDialogBuilder.setView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
```

just do it with one of the methods above, remove one.

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("SAVE",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            EditText userInput = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
                            dbUtils.insertCSVFileName(userInput.getText().toString());
                            Log.d("hi","vaqlue of edittext" + userInput.getText().toString());  //gives me null

                        }
                    })
```

use only 1 method of the two, you have used both:

```
alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);     //good practice
alertDialogBuilder.setView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
```